# How to execute a Query that list Tracks that are in an album with less than 9 songs

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have the next class in Java

```
   public class Track{
    private int id;
    private String trackName;
    private String artistName;
    private String albumName;
    private int amountMembers;
    private int duration; //segs
    private String category;
    private int albumYear;
    private boolean isSolist; //1 yes, 0 no
}
```

I got a table of Track in my Data Base (MySQL) and I want to do a query that brings me the Tracks that are in an album with less than 9 songs. How can I do it?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT.

Comment: _Suggestion_ Looks to me like you should have 2 tables for this 1) Album and 2) tracks. Link the tracks to the album

Comment: I only have  Track table

Comment: This smells like an intro-level homework question...When posting "homework" questions (or generally things in which the solution is something akin to reading textbooks) the community is here to guide you - but the question should be tagged as Homework appropriately (may not apply to this question). Additionally, questions are made better when you provide the approaches you have tried (failed attempts are good to include! we do not allow shaming here.) even if it is just a written accounting of your understanding of how you expect something to perform, vs the result you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE category = 'rock' GROUP BY album_name HAVING count(album_name) < 9 ;
```

This Query gives to me the tracks In "Rock" category with less 9 tracks in the same album